# call an Ada procedure from Fortran via DLL

Tags: dll, fortran, ada

I'm having problems with the mixed-language programming as mentioned in the title, more precisely getting arrays from Ada to the Fortran code. My Ada procedure declaration looks like:

```
    procedure Get_Double_Array
      (Double_Array    : in System.Address;
       Length_of_Array : in System.Address);
    pragma Export(Fortran, Get_Double_Array, "Get_Double_Array_");
```

The corresponding body of my procedure is

```
    procedure Get_Double_Array
      (Double_Array : in System.Address;
       Length_Of_Array : in System.Address)
    is
        use Interfaces.Fortran;

        Array_Length : Fortran_Integer;
        for Array_Length'Address use Length_Of_Array;

        Result_Array : Double_Precision_Array(1..3);
        for Result_Array'Address use Double_Array;
    begin
        Result_Array(1) := Double_Precision(1.0);
        Result_Array(2) := Double_Precision(2.0);
        Result_Array(3) := Double_Precision(3.0);

        Array_Length := Fortran_Integer(Result_Array'Last);
    end Get_Double_Array;
```

The declaration of the Double_Precision_Array looks like

```
    type Double_Precision_Array is (Fortran_Integer range <>) of Double_Precision;
    pragma Convention(Fortran, Double_Precision_Array);
```

Making this procedure available in the DLL is already working. dumpbin /exports on the created dll shows the Get_Double_Array_ as expected.

The Fortran program looks like

```
    PROGRAM TPROG
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE GETARR(DPARR, LENGTH)
    cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT, ALIAS : '_Get_Double_Array_' :: GETARR
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (:) :: DPARR
    INTEGER :: LENGTH
    END SUBROUTINE
    END INTERFACE

    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(3) :: XDOT
    INTEGER :: LENGTH
    CALL GETARR(XDOT, LENGTH)
    END PROGRAM TPROG
```

The fortran code is compiled with gfortran and linked with the lib corresponding to the created dll. The command line is

```
    gfortran -o test.exe test.f Ada_Lib.lib
```

When I inserted debugging output into the fortran code before the Call statement I can see that the Get_Double_Array procedure is called but I get the exception

```
    raised PROGRAM_ERROR: Name_Of_The_Ada_Body.adb: misaligned address value
```

The line number in this message is the one where I declare the Array_Length variable. I know about the Ada Attribute 'Alignment, but I don't know how to use it in this situation, because I'm already using Fortran compatible data types (at least I think so).

When I export the C Convention on the Ada side and also use the C convention for the array declaration and adapt the cDEC$ line in Fortran with 'C, DLLIMPORT, ALIAs', the Length value is always correct but the contents of the array are completely useless.

The range of the Arrays is only fixed for debugging. Later the Array can be of any length, which is why I also need to return the length of the array.

Any useful tipps or explanations what I'm doing wrong and what I can try next?

Comment: why you export a different symbol in Ada and in Fortran? I would use Fortran 2003 interoperability to C instead of pragmas. Not that this is DEC pragma, not GCC pragma, are you sure gfortran understands that, i think it doesn't. Also, are you sure your `double precision` means the same real type in both your languages, it can be almost anything larger than the default type, which can be anything.

Comment: @VladimirF: the name of the ada function in my lib is `_Name_`. There is a GCC pragma DLLIMPORT but `cGCC$ DLLIMPORT:: _Name_` doesn't work. The compiler doesn't accept the leading underscore.

Comment: That's why I recommend Fortran 2003 `bind(C,name="Name")` and delete all underscores.

Comment: @VladimirF: I have found some good examples how to do this with fortran 2003, but the decision to use the 2003 standard is not mine. I am supposed to use only fortran 77 constructs.

Comment: Note these pragmas are not defined anywhere in Fortran 77 standard, you are playing with problematic things and be prepared for problems. Also note you are using assumed shape arrays in your sample. This needs Fortran 90 explicit interface and will simply not work for you.

Comment: I don't know Fortran, but it doesn't seem you send the address of the parameters in the Fortran-kode, so is there any specific reason to use System.Address for the parameters in Ada? The example in Ada RM B.5 suggests it is better to just use the data types directly.

Comment: @egilhh: I'm pretty new to Fortran myself. That is why you could be correct in suggesting I don't pass adresses to the dll. I will look into this.

Comment: @egilhh I already told him he uses assumed shape arrays in his Fortran code and this is not going to work. But if he doesn't care...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Fortran has no way of passing an unconstrained array to Ada in a way that Ada understands (there's a clear correspondence to Fortan 90's assumed-shape arrays, but no way that I can see of telling the Ada side that that's what to expect).

I've been experimenting with the problem, and on Mac OS X with GCC 4.8.0 - after I remember to link in the Ada runtime - it gives the same exception that you got (by the way, what version of the compiler(s) are you using?).

When I tried passing an unconstrained array to the procedure,

```
   procedure Get_Double_Array
     (Double_Array        :    out Double_Precision_Array;
```

the compiler said

```
problem.ada:7:07: warning: type of argument "Get_Double_Array.Double_Array" is unconstrained array
problem.ada:7:07: warning: foreign caller must pass bounds explicitly
```

(why this is a warning and not an error I don't know!) and the same exception at run time.

I think what you could do is to declare an enormous array type (never actually creating one, of course):

```
with Interfaces.Fortran; use Interfaces.Fortran;
package Problematic is

   type Double_Precision_Array is
     array (Fortran_Integer range 1 .. Fortran_Integer'Last)
     of Double_Precision;
   pragma Convention (Fortran, Double_Precision_Array);

   procedure Get_Double_Array
     (Double_Array        :    out Double_Precision_Array;
      Double_Array_Length : in     Fortran_Integer;
      Output_Length       :    out Fortran_Integer);
   pragma Export(Fortran, Get_Double_Array, "get_double_array_");

end Problematic;
```

(note the lower-cased exported name), with body

```
package body Problematic is

   procedure Get_Double_Array
     (Double_Array        :    out Double_Precision_Array;
      Double_Array_Length : in     Fortran_Integer;
      Output_Length       :    out Fortran_Integer)
   is
   begin
      Double_Array(1) := Double_Precision (1.0);
      Double_Array(2) := Double_Precision (2.0);
      Double_Array(3) := Double_Precision (3.0);

      Output_Length := Fortran_Integer (3);
   end Get_Double_Array;

end Problematic;
```

with the test program changed to

```
  PROGRAM TPROG
  IMPLICIT NONE

  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(4) :: XDOT
  INTEGER :: LENGTH, J
  CALL GET_DOUBLE_ARRAY(XDOT, 4, LENGTH)
  PRINT *, 'output length is ', LENGTH
  PRINT *, (XDOT(J), J=1,LENGTH)
  END PROGRAM TPROG
```

(The compiler couldn't handle your `INTERFACE` section).

Note! so far, the Ada doesn't call up any Ada runtime facilities. If it did, you'd have to

- arrange for the runtime to be linked in
- initialize it, and possibly finalize it.

I think those would be another question!

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit more and getting help from a few colleagues we have found a soultion using C conventions.

1. I forgot the AdaInit and AdaFinal procedures. These functions are created by the binder during the creation of the dll. You must call the AdaInit function before using any functionality. Our approach to this is exporting a function like

   ```
   procedure Init_Dll;
   pragma Export(C, Init_Dll, "initdll_");
   ```

In the private part of the declaration we added

```
    procedure AdaInit;
    pragma Import(C, AdaInit);

    procedure AdaFinal;
    pragma Export(C, AdaFinal);
```

The body of our Init_Dll is straight forward

```
    procedure Init_Dll
    is
    begin
        AdaInit;
    end Init_Dll;
```

Then using gnatmake and gnatdll we created the Ada dll and with the windows command line

```
    lib -machine:IX86 -def:Name_Of_Ada_Package.def -out:Name_Of_Ada_Package.lib > nul
```

the corresponding lib

1. On the Fortran side we now used the external command instead of interfaces so the program looks like

   ```
   PROGRAM TEST
   IMPLICIT NONE
   EXTERNAL initdll
   EXTERNAL getdblarray
   INTEGER :: LENGTH
   DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(3):: ARR
   CALL initdll
   CALL getdblarray(ARR, LENGTH)
   END PROGRAM TEST
   ```

Compiling and linking this program against the created lib works just fine